# Restoring/Forwarding offline emails from Mac Mail

Tags: mac, mail.app, email

A long time ago I started using Mac Mail instead of my web-based Yahoo email. Then I deleted all my emails from my web-based Yahoo account and kept them on Mac Mail. Now that I've stopped using Mac Mail and I'm back to using web-based Yahoo, I want to know if there's any way I can restore/forward these offline emails stored on my Mac Mail back into Yahoo. There are a lot of emails, so forwarding one by one is not an option.

Someone help?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Add your Yahoo! email as IMAP and upload your mail manually from the old —presumably POP— storage on your Mail.app.

I haven't tried it myself but in recent OS X versions adding accounts is straightforward. If this is not the case and you have to configure it manually, Yahoo! offers relevant information to that effect [here](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN4075.html).